# Run jobs in parallel Pipeline script Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote below code to execute jobs in sequence in Pipeline script Jenkins, but I have a requirement to run 'build' and 'Undeploy' from below as parallel and then 'Deploy' after that

```
node: {
  stage 'build'
  build job: 'JenkinsTest', parameters: [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: "${VERSION}"],
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"],
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SET_ENV', value: "${SET_ENV}"]
    ]

stage 'Undeploy'
build job:  'Undeploy job', parameters: [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"]
    ]

stage 'Deploy'
build job:  'Deploy job', parameters: [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"]
    ]
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try with something like below, using parallel: [1](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

```
pipeline {
agent any   
stages {
    stage('First Stage'){
        steps{
            script{
                parallel(
                        "build":{
                            build job: 'JenkinsTest', parameters: [
                                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: "${VERSION}"],
                                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"],
                                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SET_ENV', value: "${SET_ENV}"]
                                ]
                        },
                        "undeploy":{
                           build job:  'Undeploy job', parameters: [
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"]
                            ]
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Second stage') {
        steps{
            script{
                build job:  'Deploy job', parameters: [
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RBFLAG', value: "${RBFLAG}"]
                    ]
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}