# Jenkins pipeline Parellel steps needs to run based on the previous step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is the Jenkisnfile script currently i am using to run my pipeline for the NodeJS applications. it's working well and suited to my previous pipeline process.

Now I Need to change a little bit in my script for the New Project Requirement.

In the **"Step B"** if the application failed to start with the **NPM Start** command, **"Step C" (build)** does not need to trigger the Job.

Now with this pipeline script approach, **"Step C" (build)** is always running whether the application failed to start or successfully run because of the parallel block.

```
pipeline {
agent any   
stages {
    stage('need to run parallelly'){
        steps{
            script{
                parallel(
                    a:{
                        dir('file path'){
                            bat """
                            npm install
                            """
                        }
                    },
                    b:{
                        dir('file path'){
                            bat """
                            npm start
                            """
                        }  
                    },
                    "build":{
                        build job: 'JenkinsTest'
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move Step C (I guess you mean the 'build'?) into a seperate stage? Jenkins will automatically stop the pipeline if A or B fails.

Comment: Since I am using the npm start command in step b, it will always be logging the API calls in the console output. if I put the npm start command in the stage or step it won't end. So the Jenkins pipeline can't reach the step c stage I mean the trigger job stage. That's why I preferred parallel blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1/ Using global boolean parameter and sleep command. I mean, estimate the time ur Stage B run the "NPM Command" finished, sleep stage C until u get NPM Command result, for eg:

```
    boolean isFail = false
Stage B:
      
      if (NPM_Command.isFail()) isFail = true
    Stage C: 
      Sleep(60) //eg 1 min is enough for run stage B
      if(isFail) 
        // do your work
```

2/ As ur comment, ur problem is Stage C cant be reach if stage B failed, [try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56976943/17119021)

Comment: hi, @himneh thank you for your answer.  I think the first solution will work for me. I have modified the script as per the first solution. But still, I am getting the same error scenario. I am thinking that I have wrongly modified the script. Can you please help me to correct the script? i have added the [GitHubrepo](https://github.com/OjerDev/jenkins-nodejs-parallel)

Comment: sorry for taking a long time to reply to your answer.